# Why doesn't running a aws s3api list-objects command return the NextToken?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm running the below command. Please note that the s3 bucket has a large number of files in it.

```
aws --profile=xxx s3api list-objects-v2 \
--bucket 'xxx' \
--max-items 2 \
--query 'Contents[].{Name: Key, LastModified: LastModified, Size: Size}'
```

According to the [aws documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-pagination.html), this should return a NextToken which I can use to get the next set of data. But the output simply contains 2 blocks with data on 2 objects in json format.

```
[
    {
        "Name": "xxx",
        "LastModified": "xxx",
        "Size": xxx
    },
    {
        "Name": "xxx",
        "LastModified": "xxx",
        "Size": xxx
    }
]
```

If I run the same command with `--output text`, it will print out the same data with a `none` at the end of it. not sure if it's related.

Comment: Because you are filtering only Name,Latmodified and size. Add 'NextToken' to the --query.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @riz. It was the query. Just had to change it to

```
--query '[{NextToken: NextToken},Contents[].{Name: Key, LastModified: LastModified, Size: Size}]'
```